# Rails 3/SQL: Database schema for ordered hierarchical (nested) data

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, schema

I'm trying to store ordered data in a database with Rails 3, in this case a table of contents that represents sections of a video:

```
Section 1, 01:23
   Section 1.1, 01:24
   Section 1.2, 02:33

Section 2, 02:23
   Section 2.1, 01:23
       Section 2.1.1, 01:50
   Section 2.2, , 01:55
```

I was going to approach the database schema like this:

```
section_id:int
parent_section:int (using a has_one relationship)
order:int (e.g. section 2.1 would be 0, section 2.2 would be 1 etc.)
video_id:int (links to a video)
length:int (length of this section of video)
```

Two questions:
1. Is this the best schema I could use to approach the problem?
2. Does Rails 3 have a built in way of working with this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great answer since I have not evaluated these gems for use with rails 3, but..

The two methods of dealing with this type of data I know from Rails 2 are acts_as_tree and acts_as_nested_set(and awesome_nested_set). It appears people have mixed results getting these going on rails3.

A quick google search yielded the NestedSet gem for Rails 3. You may want to evaluate it to see if it fits your needs. https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set

Comment: That Nested Set gem did the trick, only one I found that works on Rails 3